# C# Highlight words that end with colon

Tags: c#, regex, search, syntax, highlighting

I am using ScintillaNet, a wrapper for the Scintilla control in my C# application. I am dynamically adding all words that end with : (let's just call this keyword from now). I did this by using a regex the string of keywords separated by a whitespace every time the user presses the colon key. Here is my code (in the CharAdded event):

```
        if (e.Ch == ':')
        {
            string wp = string.Empty;
            Regex r = new Regex(@"\b\w+[:\b]");
            MatchCollection m = r.Matches(Scintilla.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < m.Count; i++)
            {
                wp += " " + m[i].Value.Substring(0, m[i].Value.Length - 1); // Remove the colon
            }
            wp = wp.ToLower();
            Scintilla.Lexing.Keywords[3] = wp;
        }
```

Now the problem is, every time a new keyword is typed and the user presses the colon, instead of just highlighting the keyword, it will unnecessarily highlight every single keyword in the document again. So although my coding works, it's pretty bad coding, and I am wondering how I can make my code faster by only highlighting the last keyword typed. Any help and/or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you should remove the `\b` from inside the character class. Firstly, it doesn't mean "word boundary" in this context, secondly, `\b` won't match after a colon anyway, unless the following character is an alphanumeric. Just use `\b\w+:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not unnecessary actually, You may only check for the last word but what if user pastes a long text? You really have to check every word one by one unless you are sure that the user won't paste a text into the control or edit the middle of the text..

Comment: Well, I already planned to use this code for things like pasting (I'd use it in the TextInserted event), but it really seems poor to highlight every single word again when the user only types one. There is sometimes a lag of about 1-2 seconds when the user types a colon, and it can get very annoying for long documents.

Comment: There is no easy way of doing it, you may only check if the keyword is already highlighted (I couldn't find the part where you highlight the word in your code?? It looks like it only adds every word that matches to your regex to Scintilla.Lexing.Keywords and I don't know what that is..)

Comment: The only other part that I left out for highlighting was Scintilla.Styles[12].ForeColor = Color.blah. Scintilla itself handles the lexing/colorizing, I just supply the keywords. Also, how would I check if a keyword is already highlighted using a regex? That is what I wanted to do, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is really long and you want to improve your processing time, then what about trying to insert a hidden tag that flags the words as "highlighted" and ignoring these in your regular expression ?

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I don't know how I could do it with a regex. Could you explain?